# how to implement current_request in aiohttp server application

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Hi I'm writing database extension for SQLALchemy.

Regarding to SQLAlchemy documentation page: [Using Custom Created Scopes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#using-custom-created-scopes)

I need function that returns current request.

You have ideas on how to implement such function in aiohttp server app?

```
class MyApp(web.Application):

    def get_current_request(self):
        # TODO
        pass
```

Comment: aiohttp discourages this approach, instead, you should pass the request object around as it's used. One potential approach is to use class based views. https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web.html#class-based-views. Or you can roll your own like https://github.com/tutorcruncher/morpheus/blob/master/morpheus/app/utils.py#L45

Comment: You just cannot use SQLAlchemy ORM with any async framework -- it kills performance. The only way is running all SQL queries in thread pool -- or using low level libraries like aiopg and asyncpg

Answer (score 2):

Currently the only option is to explicitly pass a request object (from handler) to wherever you need to. Without that, outside the handler it's hard to say which request is the current one.

It's worth to note that there is a light in a tunnel - [PEP 550](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0550/) (also look on [PEP 521](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0521/)). By now it is only a draft but it could help to pass such a variables in async context almost as with TLS (Thread-local storage `threading.local()`).